# loop through a single column in one dataframe compare to a column in another dataframe create new column in first dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

right now I have two dataframes they look like:

```
c = pd.DataFrame({'my_goal':[3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                 'low_number': [0,100,1000,2000,3000],
                 'high_number': [100,1000,2000,3000,4000]})
```

and

```
a= pd.DataFrame({'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                'Number':[50, 500, 1030, 2005 , 3575]})
```

what I want to do is if  'Number' falls between the low number and the high number I want it to bring back the value in 'my_goal'. For example if we look at 'a' it's 'Number is is 100 so I want it to bring back 3. I also want to create a dataframe that contains all the columns from dataframe a and the 'my_goal' column from dataframe c. I want the output to look like:

[image]

I tried making my high and low numbers into a separate list and running a for loop from that, but all that gives me are 'my_goal' numbers:

```
low_number= 'low_number': [0,100,1000,2000,3000]
for i in a:
    if float(i) >= low_number:
        a = c['my_goal']

print(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`, when I see ranges, I first think of pd.cut:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfc = pd.DataFrame(c)

dfa['my_goal'] = pd.cut(dfa['Number'],
                        bins=[0]+dfc['high_number'].tolist(),
                        labels=dfc['my_goal'])
```

Output:

```
   a  Number my_goal
0  a      50       3
1  b     500       4
2  c    1030       5
3  d    2005       6
4  e    3575       7
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed row 4 slightly to include a test case where the condition is not met. You can concat a with rows of c where the condition is true.

```
a= pd.DataFrame({'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],'Number':[50, 500, 1030, 1995 , 3575]})
cond= a.Number.between( c.low_number, c.high_number)

pd.concat([a, c.loc[cond, ['my_goal']] ], axis = 1, join = 'inner')


    Number  a   my_goal
0   50      a   3
1   500     b   4
2   1030    c   5
4   3575    e   7
```

Comment: I am trying this solution now and am getting the value error can only compare identically-labeled series objects. I am seeing this on the cond, and I cant tell if it is on the 'a.Number' or c columns. I tried using `reset_index(drop=True)` for all three of these and it did not work. This is what i have tried `a.number = a.number.reset_index(drop=True)` `c.low_number = c.low_number.reset_index(drop = True)` and `c.high_number= c.high_number.reset_index(drop = True)`.